# Is it possible that a url link within an email can be auto-executed by an email client?

Tags: php, html, email

We have a script that executes different actions when a user clicks on a specified URL from within the received email. We are getting random records in our database as soon as we send the email to the user. We've checked that we do not have any PHP functions that execute those URLs. So we ask here, is it possible that a URL within an email body can be auto-executed by an email client?

Comment: Thank you! Any idea what it can be?

Comment: Some mail clients will pre-load links, and/or check link targets for malicious content, which might be the source of those records. I'm curious though, how have you ruled out that those records are not caused by users clicking?

Comment: The records are created immediately upon send (with a second), so no time for user to be clicking. That's what we thought re the preload links however this is inconsistent as for the same user one time it works ok and the next it creates erroneous records?

Comment: There should be no reason why a link would be followed or visited by an email client/server. Imagine all the unsubscribes if gmail visited every unsubscribe link from an email. I would go look at the web server access logs to get more information regarding who/what visited the link. It wouldn't surprise me if you saw user agents listing spam services or even just standard browsers if someone actually clicked the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that wouldn't be a good thing.