# MySQL field seemingly updates randomly

Tags: php, mysql

In using sourced registration code that includes email verification, I am experiencing odd behaviour. Can't get  my head round this.

In running the same code on a localhost installation on a PC (PHP V7.2.18 and MySQL V5.7.26) and on a live site (PHP Version 7.2.27 and MariaDB V5.5.65), the registration code, which sends a verification email, works as expected. The DB structure is exactly the same.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `useremail` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `userpassword` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `termcondition` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `userstatus` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `token` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Of interest is the **userstatus** field. 0 on insert; updated to 1 on verification by email.

Upon registration, the following code is executed:

```
    $data       =   array(
                        'useremail'=>$signupemail,
                        'username'=>$signupusername,
                        'userpassword'=>$hash,
                        'termcondition'=>$signupcondition,
                        'userstatus'=>0,**
                        'token'=>$token
                        );
    $insert     =   $db->insert('tb_user',$data);
```

On verifying via an email link, the following code is executed:

```
$token=isset($_REQUEST['token'])?$_REQUEST['token']:''; 
            
if($token!=""){
$userData = $db->getQueryCount('tb_user','id',' AND token="'.$token.'"');

  if(isset($userData[0]['total']) and $userData[0]['total']>0){
  $update = $db->update(
   'tb_user',array(
   'token'=>"",
   'userstatus'=>1),
   array('token'=>$token));

if($update){ //success!
}
```

Here lies the problem. On the live site ONLY, and before verification, the userstatus is updated **randomly,** to 1.Stripping code, renaming files and commenting code have not resolved the problem. I'm left with the conclusion that the behaviour is, somehow, dictated by the DB.I realize this may sound odd, and that I may well be requested to post more code, but as said, the same code is parsed on the localhost and the live site with different outcomes.

**UPDATED**: Thanks @simon.ro. Had looked at this before, but ignored it because the only place where the userstatus is updated is in verify.php (as in the last code posted above), and the only reference to verify.php is in the activation link, which is sent by email. The userstatus is updated before the activation link is clicked. Below is the relevant code from action-form.php, which generates the activation link:

```
$token    = md5(uniqid('lcw-'.mt_rand(),true)); //token to verify registration
$tokenUrl = HOME_URL.'verify.php?token='.$token; //activation link

if($db_insert){ // user registration data captured

    //Generate verification email
    $header =   "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $header .=  "Content-Type: text/HTML; charset=ISO-8859-1 \n";
    $body = 'Dear '.$signupusername.'<p><a href='.$tokenUrl.'>Please click here to activate your account</a></p>'; 
    .....
    $mail=mail($to,$subject,$body,$header);
```

However, today I find the following entry in the error log whenever the email is sent:

```
script '/var/www/html/test/verify.php' not found or unable to stat
```

I know this can't be the case, but it appears that the activation link is somehow activated (for lack of a better word) when the email is sent. When I comment $mail out, then the userstatus is not updated, nor is there an entry in the error log.

It is exactly the same problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35462868/is-it-possible-that-a-url-link-within-an-email-can-be-auto-executed-by-an-email/66185732#66185732)

Comment: We can't tell if the `$token` is unique, and we cannot tell what the `$userData[0]['total']` represents. Is it the total number of times the token is found? That makes it hard to debug your code.

Comment: There's that MyISAM again.

Comment: @Strawberry Please clarify your remark.

Comment: The token is unique $token  = md5(uniqid('lcw-'.mt_rand(),true));
 $tokenUrl = home_url.'verify.php?token='.$token;

Comment: That code doesn't guarantee an unique token, but I agree it highly unlikely to generate the same token twice. Nevertheless if `$db->getQueryCount()` does indeed return the number of rows with the given `$token` I would use this check: `$userData[0]['total'] == 1`, not `$userData[0]['total'] > 0`. Just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @kikisoftware if memory serves, MyISAM ceased being the default engine 10 years ago

Comment: **WARNING**: ` AND token="'.$token.'"'` is a SQL injection bug.

Comment: MyISAM is an obsolete database engine. It doesn't have transactions or a journal to ensure integrity and a server crash can easily corrupt MyISAM tables beyond repair. It's not worth using. InnoDB can be tuned to perform better, is transactional, and can recover from all but the most severe of server crashes without a hitch.

Comment: Thanks for the better code @kikosoftware. This, however, occurs randomly within 1 to 5 registrations, which makes it less likely. I'm GMT + 2, so will  check tomorrow for responses/guidance.

Comment: I suspect there are other places in your codebase that update userstatus.